# SSH only works if I specify the key with -i

Tags: debian, ssh

I have a server that only allows ssh with a key. However when I try to ssh to this machine I get the error "Permission denied (publickey)". From the auth.log on my server this is happening pre auth. The permissions on my keys and .ssh folder look fine. Also if I use -vv when attempting to ssh it doesn't appear to be attempting to use the correct key file.

The only way this works is if I use the -i arg and specify the path to the key. (Which is in my .ssh folder) I've installed key before and had no problems. The only difference was that this time I had to scp the key file to the server and then use cat >> to add it to the authorised key file, rather than use ssh-copy-id.

Does anyone know how I could debug this further or fix the issue rather than make me server unsecure for a while and then use ssh-copy-id?

-vv output (the key that's valid doesn't even get tried for some reason.)

```
OpenSSH_6.7p1 Raspbian-5+deb8u2, OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to $host [$ip address] port $port.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ben/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ben/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ben/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ben/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ben/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ben/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ben/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ben/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Raspbian-5+deb8u2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: setup umac-64-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
debug2: mac_setup: setup umac-64-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 10:b9:0c:fa:8f:69:f2:eb:84:bd:69:32:50:1b:dd:ee
debug1: Host '$host' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ben/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/ben/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/ben/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/ben/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/ben/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ben/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ben/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ben/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ben/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Details of the `.ssh` directory and content,

```
ls - ld
drwxr-xr-x 2 $user $user .

ls -l
total 16
-rw------- 1 $user $user 733 May 3 16:27 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 $user $user 3243 May 9 15:33 key 
-rw-r--r-- 1 $user $user 751 May 9 15:33 key.pub 
-rw-r--r-- 1 $user $user 444 May 9 15:31 known_hosts
```

Comment: Do you have a config file in your .ssh directory (on the machine you ssh *from*) which is over-riding the key?  Can you post the output from `ssh -vv` in your question.

Comment: There's no config in my .ssh folder just keys, authorised_keys and known_hosts.

Comment: What's the filename of the valid key?  Can you include `ls -ld /home/user/.ssh` and `ls -l /home/user/.ssh`

Comment: ls - ld `drwxr-xr-x 2 $user $user .` ls -l total 16
`-rw------- 1 $user $user  733 May  3 16:27 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 $user $user 3243 May  9 15:33 key
-rw-r--r-- 1 $user $user 751 May  9 15:33 key.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 $user $user  444 May  9 15:31 known_hosts`

Comment: The key is key and key.pub

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but the permissions on `.ssh` should be 700 rather than 755.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. I've changed it but still no results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, `ssh` only searches for keys with the name `id_rsa`, `id_dsa` and a few others which all start `id_` as show in the output in your question.  If you have keys named anything else you must specify them on the command line, or in an ssh config file.

Either rename your file `key` to something ssh searches for, or update `.ssh/config` with a relevant stanza, or use the `-i` option.

You can use something like this in `.ssh/config`

```
host my.target.server
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key
```

You can also use,

```
host *
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key
```

to force ssh to use `~/.ssh/key` for all connections.

It may be easier to rename the key file to `id_dsa` or `id_rsa` though (assuming the file is actually called `key` as in your output).

Comment: Strange the config trick worked. However I've never had this issue on my other machines and their keys aren't named id_rsa, etc.

Comment: There are several options that allow ssh to use other keys, including `ssh_agent`, global options in `/etc/ssh/config`, etc.  However, your output shows that the ssh client does not find the file named key and so never uses it - and I believe that's the default behaviour.

Comment: I can't see any differences between this machine and my other machines global config wise. My other machines use the default config. The only difference is OS maybe that's what it is. Most of my machines use debian Jessie but the machine I had the issue sshing from is raspbian wheezy.

Comment: Just tested on Debian Jessie, and only files named `id_` are picked by default.  Otherwise I have to specify them.  There's got to be either an `ssh-agent` running, or some other global or local config option which is letting it find other files.  If you can document the difference in behaviour, open another question asking why they differ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `MaxAuthTries` directive in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. The default value is set to 6. If you have more local keys which are tried before the one you explicitly set using the `-i` option, logon may be denied if the number of tries exceed the value of `MaxAuthTries`.

For more information see also `man sshd_config`

Comment: You can see from the `-vv` output that it's not finding any keys, so it's not exhausting the `MaxAuthTries` option.

Comment: I only have one key but I gave it a go anyway. Still no luck.